# How to use Salt pkg.installed module to install local rpm

Tags: yum, salt-stack

We have some .rpm applications we wanted to install on CentOS 6 & 7 machines.  The machines don't have access to internet.  How can we write a state that would make sure the application is installed? Here's my code:

```
Install Nessus Agent:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: NessusAgent
    - sources: '[{"NessusAgent": "salt:///root/NessusAgent-7.1.1-es{{ osmajorrelease }}.x86_64.rpm"}]'
```

Error I get when I ran the state:

```
     Comment: An exception occurred in this state: Traceback (most recent call last):
                File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/state.py", line 1913, in call
                  **cdata['kwargs'])
                File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/loader.py", line 1898, in wrapper
                  return f(*args, **kwargs)
                File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/states/pkg.py", line 1617, in installed
                  if next(iter(list(x.keys()))) in targets]
              AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

What is the correct way to install local rpm packages with a Salt state?

Comment: I know I can use the cmd.run execution module and write it like this:
<code>
Install Nessus Agent:
  cmd.run:
    - name: yum -y --nogpgcheck localinstall /root/NessusAgent-7.1.1-es6.x86_64.rpm
</code>
but then it would run the install every time and is not idempotent.   I would prefer to make it a system State declaration using the SALT.STATES.PKG that would ensure that the program only got installed if it's not already installed.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by rewriting the "sources" parameter:

```
Install Nessus Agent:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: NessusAgent
    - enable: True
    - sources:
      - NessusAgent: salt:///files/nessus/NessusAgent-7.1.1-es7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: The `name` parameter is not required when providing the `sources` list, since the name is given as the key for each source (`NessusAgent` in this case). Also, `enable` is not a valid parameter for `pkg.installed` in recent versions of Salt.